# After recovering from a cold, I always wake up with some phlegm in my throat

Tags: common-cold, lasting-effects-duration, waking-up, mucus-phlegm, throat

I used to never have to clear my throat after waking up, but around 4 months ago I caught a cold that took a long time to clear up.

Now when I wake up, I always find that my throat needs clearing. It never used to be this way. What can I do about it? Should I be worried?

Comment: You can visit your doctor and they can answer all your questions after a physical examination. There is no way for us to do it on-line.